# Failed to reboot after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 - is LVM the problem?

Tags: boot, upgrade, 22.04, troubleshooting

AFAICT, my problem is different from others with this same title.

- My computer is a HP Proliant MicroServer.
- It was running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 without any problems and was fully up to date before I ran do-release-upgrade.
- Ubuntu is the only OS on this computer.
- I have LVM set up on this computer, mainly for RAID.

After the do-release-upgrade completed without any obvious problem, I rebooted as prompted.  The boot process ended by dropping into emergency mode.

Going through the log with journalctl -xb (as recommended in the emergency mode prompt) I saw a number of errors but the first one that looked relevant to me was a failure to mount the boot partition:

```
: mount: /boot: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
: boot.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
```

A bit further on in the log, I saw this:

```
: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
: ECT4-fs (sdd1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
```

I have tried running fsck /dev/sdd1 but it reports that the filesystem is clean.

What else do I need to know to diagnose and repair my upgraded system?

Also, I have transcribed the above from the screen of the HP Proliant computer but this would be a tedious and error-prone process for larger volumes of diagnostics.  What is the best way to copy/paste the diagnostics from another computer?  If I boot using a Ubuntu Live USB stick, will I be able to access the boot log and other diagnostics from the computer itself?  If so how do I do that?

TIA,

Comment: Yes, a LiveCD will give you the ability to mount and examine your "normal" system - the usual LVM commands like "pvs", "lvs", ... should work just out of the box. You can even "chroot" into your normal system and run commands like apt, dpkg, ... from "in the system". Here's a how-to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/chroot-environment-linux

Comment: BTW today I upgraded an elderly HP Microserver from 20.04 to 22.04, and landed on the emergency "busybox" prompt. Turns out, I had set up the boot+root partitions with the motherboard's fakeraid controller as RAID1, but the new initrd did not contain neither the dm_mirror module nor partprobe. I resolved the issue in a few hours using a USB rescue-system to build a suitable initramfs.

Comment: Ubuntu 21 and 22 will not boot in my older VirtualBox setup unless I first modify the grub `quiet splash` to be `quiet splash nomodeset` -- this means that I do that initially when booting for the first time by pressing the escape key to get the grub interface and then pressing the `e` key and making edits; and, then rebooting, and when Ubuntu is up and running the default grub needs to be updated with the same type of `quiet splash nomodeset` ...  I read that it could be Wayland instead of X11 and once its up and running you can change back to X11, but the grub edit seems to do the trick.

Comment: you can try using this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had limited time to investigate this until today unfortunately, but the solution to my problem ended up being quite simple!

As mentioned, the computer in question uses LVM for RAID, but the ***root*** partition is also on a Logical Volume.  The boot partition was on sdd1 and prior to the upgrade it had been ext2 format.  It appears that during the upgrade, the boot partition file system was reformatted to ext4 ***but*** the fstab wasn't changed to reflect this.

To fix my problem, all I had to do was boot from a Live USB, mount the Root partition (which was in a logical volume so I used LVM commands detailed in the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/chroot-environment-linux link that [@Hannes Erven](https://askubuntu.com/users/1069813/hannes-erven) posted, edit my /etc/fstab and change the filetype for the boot mount from ext2 to ext4.

So,

```
UUID=a21e0795-3317-4436-808b-87b5e03126c5 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
```

became

```
UUID=a21e0795-3317-4436-808b-87b5e03126c5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

I'm wondering if there is a bug in the upgrade process whereby it updates the format of the boot partition if it's outdated, but then doesn't update fstab when that file is located on a LVM partition?

Many thanks to those who offered suggestions!